# iTerm2 Highlighting Prompt Line

Tags: highlight, iterm2

For some reason on a single box, my command line is being fully lit purple background by `iTerm2`.  I have no memory of doing this as I don't know how to, nor would I want this.  My `export PS1="...` is the same as another box which doesn't do this.  So this is why I think this is `iTerm2` doing this.  Also it has a bit of a delay before this happens.

How can I keep this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

It was a `trigger`.  `Triggers` been a bit wonky with the current beta.  Fixed by deleting the `trigger`.